# Cors for allowed origin in node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, cors

I have started working in node. I am learning cors() in node, I need to allow cors for only google.com, apart from that if anyone accesses then I need to block the origin

Below is my code but it allows all origins, so can you please help me how to overcome it

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
 import express from 'express';
 import cors from 'cors';

 app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.google.com/");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
       "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
     next();
 });
 app.get("/",  (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        'message':' Hello world !!! the app is listening on port '
    })   
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening to requests on ');
});
```

Below are my console logs for google.com and stackoverflow.com. However, my code is working on both origins which is wrong

[image]

[image]

Comment: your should check in your response and request headers are correct as per your settings..

Comment: You are also not using the cors library correctly, you are requiring the library but not using it as middleware.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. so please let me know about another solution.

Comment: I added an answer for you check if that works.

Comment: @Obsidianlab yes it works ,there is / issue in allow origin .

Comment: I dont understand. What exacty is the issue now? If my answer helped upvote it and mark as complete. If there is a new error throw it under the question or ask a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try actually using the cors library you are importing as follows.

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://google.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
 
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```